# complexity of instanceof operator java

Tags: java, performance, complexity-theory

I was wondering how computationally expensive is using instanceof operator in java and wanted to know if there are any better alternatives available

Comment: Whether there are any alternatives depends on what you need to do...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The alternative is to avoid using `instanceof` and design your classes properly (in OO sense).

As the `instanceof` operator has a corresponding "[instanceof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.instanceof)" byte code instruction, there probably won't be a more performant approach; but this may also depend on how the actual JVM optimizes.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.  The question is essentially, "In order to do X (where X is unstated) I must do Y; how fast is Y and are there any alternatives?"  You propose not doing X at all, which isn't addressing OP's point.

Comment: @MichaelMcGowan: From my experience `instanceof` is often a related to bad design. For me, not using it is the best alternative. And if you are not using it, you don't need to be concerned about it's performance.

Comment: I fully agree that it is *often* related to a bad design.  However, that doesn't mean it is always the case, and sometimes for various reasons one is stuck with a bad design.

Comment: @MichaelMcGowan the fastest way to do anything is not to do it, so that alternative should always be explored. It is the null-hypothesis technique.

Answer (score 9):

`instanceof` is pretty damn fast. However, it's generally a symptom of a poorly thought out design.

It'll have around the same performance as a (successful) cast, as it is doing much the same thing. Indeed, the task is roughly equivalent to a "virtual" method call.

On sane implementations: For classes, it's just a matter of getting the runtime class and looking at a fixed offset to check the superclass (so long as you don't have an inheritance chain of more than eight classes for HotSpot). Interfaces are a bit more tricky, but generally have the last two used cases for any particular runtime class cached. So that's also fast.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if the object is an instance of a certain class (but not if it `extends` or `implements` it), maybe comparing the classes with `==` would be faster :

```
o.getClass() == YourClass.class
```

Otherwise since the `instanceof` keyword has been created for this specific purpose I don't see how you could ever do better..

Comment: I don't think this is faster,because  ` ref instanceof class` is directly mapped into the `instanceof` bytecode operation. Your approach adds the method call `getClass`.

Comment: The comparison you are attempting with `getClass` will not work when attempting to check whether the object also belongs to a certain subclass. For instance, if you have `FileReader` extending `InputStreamReader` which in turn extends/implements `Reader`, calling `getClass` on an object instantiated with `new FileReader` will never yield anything else than `FileReader` class, and so `o.getClass() == Reader` or `o.getClass() == InputStreamReader` will both evaluate to `false`. `instanceof`, on the other hand, will yield `true` in all three class cases.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have actually profiled your code and found that your use of `instanceof` is a non-trivial performance hit?  If not, you're almost certainly solving a problem that isn't worth your time to be solving.

If all you're doing is code like this:

```
if ( something instanceof MyClass ) {
    MyClass mySomething = (MyClass) something;
    //...
} else {
    //exceptional case
}
```

Then it might be possible to try the cast first, and allow the `ClassCastException` to be your "exceptional case":

```
try {
   MyClass mySomething = (MyClass) something;
} catch (ClassCastException cce) {
    //exceptional case
}
```

Now, while it may be premature *optimization*, it would not be premature to rethink your design.  Overuse of `instanceof` is a design smell.  In general, you should be using generics and polymorphism in ways that reduce the number of times you'd use `instanceof` (and indeed casting) to (nearly) zero.

1. If different code should be run depending on the type of the object, consider making that code an instance method of the object and having the different types conform to an interface.
2. If you find yourself "knowing" that an object is of a certain type but you've done some step that makes the compiler lose track of that fact (e.g. you put it into a raw `List`), it might be a candidate for generification.